# CSS-In-Js Using aphrodite style object with string class names on one html element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, gatsby, reactstrap, aphrodite

My existing project using Bootstrap and looks like:

```
<ul className=”nav navbar-nav”>
```

But Aphrodite asks for something like:

```
<ul className={css(styles.red)}>
```

Question:

How can I merge these 2 approaches?

```
<ul className=”nav navbar-nav” className={css(styles.red)}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 template literal:
 `` className={`nav navbar-nav ${css(styles.red)}`} ``

or the `join()` method:
`className={['nav navbar-nav',css(styles.red)].join(' ')}`

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o7l833lym6

Comment: That's odd! I tried to use css(), and I console.log it and found it's something like this: '  backgroundColor: "#eed" '. Not sure what happened.... but this works. Thank you